# Abnormal data usage raspbian

Tags: linux, internet, raspbian

I have notice a signification data usage on my pi even when I am not using it. this can be a problem as I am using a IOT sim card with a limited bandwidth. my goal is to stay under 5Mb/day however it's around 50-500Mb a day even when I am not using it

I have setup iftop and monitored the traffic for a couple hours. I haven't seen anything abnormal excepts
few connections to some NTP and DNS servers

both iftop and vnstat do not offer a way to see a detailed datausage for past days in order to pin point the process that used the data.

is there anything I can try or can you advise ?

Comment: It's not a Pi specific problem.  Any box connected to the internet transfers data which you might want to monitor.

Comment: Asking duplicate Questions won't help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Abnormal data usage raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112838/abnormal-data-usage-raspbian)

Comment: @Milliways The OP was [advised by *goldilocks*](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112838/abnormal-data-usage-raspbian#comment193692_112838) to ask at [Super User](http://superuser.com/). Now its coming back from there. Seems no one like to help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have UFW enabled? If not, I would recommend installing it and setting it up to block all outgoing connections. To install, open Terminal and type `sudo apt install ufw`. Then, `sudo ufw enable` to enable the firewall. Then, type `sudo ufw defaults deny incoming && sudo ufw defaults deny outgoing`. After you do that, restart your firewall by typing `sudo ufw disable && sudo ufw enable`. You can allow certain applications or ports with the `sudo ufw allow <name>` command. See this [link](https://www.tecmint.com/setup-ufw-firewall-on-ubuntu-and-debian/) for more. The firewall will simply help you make sure that malware isn't connecting to the internet and gives you more control over what can connect to the internet.

Comment: this sounds like a good idea. does how about the NTP servers the pi connects to to get the time? how about updates? just turn the incoming traffic back on before updates?

Comment: That should all be allowed automatically. I’m pretty sure UFW allows basic services to still function.